# Magento 2 - unable to retrieve deployment of static files from the file system storeview

Tags: magento2, developer-mode

When I'm in production mode, if i run the command

> php bin magento setup: upgrade

static files are generated only for the en_US language. 
While for the other store views, it_IT and es_ES I get the error: 
unable to retrieve deployment of static files from the file system storeview

I have to generate manually with the command:

> php bin / magento setup: static-content: deploy - f it_IT

.... It's normal? 
Because when I'm in Developer mode and I run the command:

```
php bin magento setup: upgrade
```

They are automatically generated for all store view.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding  of the Magento documentation (link below) is that unless specified one language or all languages, **en_US** is the default language.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

If you try the command below:

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy it_IT es_ES
```

It should work and get something like this as a result:

```
Deploy using quick strategy
adminhtml/Magento/backend/it_IT         2193/2193           ============================ 100% %  10 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/it_IT            2180/2180           ============================ 100% %  9 secs
adminhtml/Magento/backend/es_ES         2193/2193           ============================ 100% %  11 secs
frontend/Magento/blank/es_ES            2180/2180           ============================ 100% %  9 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/it_IT             2195/2195           ============================ 100% %  12 secs
frontend/Magento/luma/es_ES             2195/2195           ============================ 100% %  12 secs
```